# can i get static maps in Google Maps API V3?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Does anyone know if its possible to get the Static Maps (image maps) for the API V3?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

think i've got an answer:

http://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-js-api-v3/browse_thread/thread/cfff8fa093c48132/db381fe992d65233?lnk=gst&q=static#db381fe992d65233

Answer (score 6):

Google Static Maps API is a different API than Google Maps API.

Note than Google Maps API V3 use static map when the map is loading so you can view a map faster. Same technique explain here http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/static+js.html for Google Maps API V2.

Answer (score 0):

As explained earlier the Static Maps API is version 2.
Here's a good doc:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/

At least, that is my quick understanding after a quick search. The only time I create a static map is usually at the end of a directions page, where I have already created an interactive map. I have a div with an ID of "StaticMap", Then I use this function:

```
function makeStaticMap(Destination,LatLon)
{
    Dest = Destination.split(",");
    Dest[0] = Dest[0].replace(/ /gi, "+");
    Dest[1] = Dest[1].replace(/ /gi, "+");
    var StaticLink = '<img src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center='+Dest[0]+','+Dest[1]+','+Dest[2]+'&zoom=16&size=600x300&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:blue%7Clabel:%7C'+LatLon+'&sensor=false" />';
    var LinkDiv = document.getElementById("StaticMap");
    LinkDiv.innerHTML = StaticLink;
}
```

Where LatLon, of course, is a comma-separated string and Destination is "Address,City,State,ZipCode".

Hope this helps.